How do I perform a permutation test on a machine learning model to obtain a p-value for its performance?
this is kinda of the same question of this previous post. But since there's no reply, and I'm having a hard time to find some answers, I'd like to ask it again.
I'm training a regression model (SVM linear kernel) in caret. And I've used a software a few times called PRONTO, that can run a permutation test to obtain a p-value for the predictive model metrics (R², MSE, etc.).
How can I reproduce this in R? Is it possible to do it within the caret package?
EDIT 1:
After some reading of the book Introduction to statistical learning, page 587, I think I did what I wanted. But I want to confirm if this approach is ok.
First, I needed to do a small change to the code provided by the caret package to get the best results from the model trained. This small change is to obtain only the RSquared from the model with best tune.
get_best_rsquared = function(caret_fit) {
  best = which(rownames(caret_fit$results) == rownames(caret_fit$bestTune))
  best_result = caret_fit$results[best, "Rsquared"]
  rownames(best_result) = NULL
  best_result
}

Now, I'll use the mtcars data frame as an example and train the model:
set.seed(42)
model <- train( mpg ~ drat+wt, data = mtcars, 
method = "svmLinear",
preProc = c("center","scale"),
tuneGrid = expand.grid(C = c(0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000)),
trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 5, savePredictions = TRUE))

Now, we can do the permutations to the mpg variable:
B <- 10
n <- length(mtcars[,1])
Tbs <- rep(NA, B)

set.seed(42)

for (b in 1:B) {

X <- mtcars[c("drat","wt")]

Y <- sample(mtcars[,1], size = n, replace = FALSE)

dat <- cbind(X, Y)

mperm <- train(Y ~ .,
data = dat,
method = "svmLinear",
preProc = c("center","scale"),
tuneGrid = expand.grid(C = c(0.01,0.1,1,10,100,1000)),
trControl = trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 5, savePredictions = TRUE))

Tbs[b] <- get_best_rsquared(mperm)

}

And here, we can obtain the p-value from this null distribution of rsquared
mean((abs(Tbs) >= abs(get_best_rsquared(model))))

Is this approach ok? Is there something I can do to improve the code? I'm not a programmer nor a statistician. Other question that I have is, should I run this permutation with the best tune of the original model, or let the permuted model find its own best tune? Thanks in advance.

A $p$-value expresses $\mathrm{Pr}(\mathrm{data} | \mathrm{H}_0)$. For $R^2$, I suppose you could test against $\mathrm{H}_0: R^2 = 0$, but a what would you even test against for the MSE? What would the added value be of this $p$-value?

Some considerations that would need to be addressed: 1. What's the null and alternative you're trying to test, exactly? What would be an exchangeable quantity under that null? (e.g. in a simple regression with a null of $\beta=0$, the y's are presumably exchangeable when that's true, so you just permute the y's to generate the permutation distribution of your chosen statistic in that case).

We'd need to know what exactly PRONTO does. The PRONTO manual is here: http://www.mlnl.cs.ucl.ac.uk/pronto/prt_manual.pdf I have seen one occurrence of a permutation test there but there may be more. Unfortunately my impression is that the documentation doesn't explain the test in a rigorous enough way that I could reproduce it, however this may be due to the extremely small amount of time I spent reading this and thinking about it. May be there are references somewhere. You could help by pointing us to a specific place in the documentation relevant to your question.

Permutation tests of regression models usually add permuted residuals back to the fitted values, re-fit the same model, and compute a goodness of fit statistic. This creates a population of $n!$ GoF statistics corresponding to all $n!$ permutations of $n$ residuals.  The permutation p-value measures how far out in the (lower) tail of the population the original GoF statistic is.  (In practice, because $n!$ is enormous, the population can only be sampled, whence the p-value can only be estimated.) This procedure is relatively easy to code in R.

@ChristianHennig the section 5.4.3 is where the authors comment about this permutation test: "PRoNTo will estimate the model for the specified number of repetitions with permuted labels/targets, and produce a p-value for performance statistics". From my lay perspective, what I understood is that it permutes Y, run the training/test, gets a model metric, and repeat n times, then do a hypothesis test with the original metric vs the ones derived from the Y permutations.

It was already said in the comments, but you can proceed roughly as follows. State your null-hypothesis. This null-hypothesis should be sufficiently detailed to generate random data of reasonable similarity to what you have in the experiment. You then generate that data, apply your statistic calculation to that data, iterate, and extract an empirical distribution for that statistic. You then compare your statistic value obtained in the experiment with that distribution. p-value can be read from it directly.
For example, lets say you want to know whether six observations came from the standard normal distribution, and you only have the fifth largest observation to test it. Your statistic can be the 5th value itself. Your null hypothesis is that $X_i \sim Normal(0,1)$. You draw ordered sample tuples $\{X^{(k)}_1\le X^{(k)}_2\dots \le X^{(k)}_6\}$ (you draw them and then you order them). You then extract your sampled statistic $\{X^{(1)}_5,\,X^{(2)}_5\dots\}$. Finally you compare your experimental value $x_5$ with the empirical cumulative probability density $F_{X_5}\left(\dots\right)$. The right-sided p-value would then be $1-F_{X_5}\left(x_5\right)$.
What you need to do is specify your null-hypothesis now. Ideally, something that generates data that you can run your regression over. The extract your results, statistics, etc. Can't say much more without knowing what your data is.

@ChristianHennig, I needed a simple example that involved sampling and extracting a non-trivial statistic from a sample. Yes all 6 measurements get sampled from N(0,1) then you select the 5th one as a statistic. Example of where this could be? You get six pallets from the factory from the single material intake, heaviest pallet goes to premium customer, 5 other ones get loaded into a truck. Load balancing demands that pallets are arranged in the order of the weight. QA is done on the pallet at the end since it is easiest to access.

@ChristianHennig, I appreciate the edit. The wording was a bit off, indeed
